# How to find the index of a value in 2d array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I need to figure out how I can find all the index of a value in a 2d numpy array.

For example, I have the following 2d array:

```
([[1 1 0 0],
  [0 0 1 1],
  [0 0 0 0]])
```

I need to find the index of all the 1's and 0's.

```
1: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)]
0: [(0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 0), (1, 1), (the entire all row)]
```

I tried this but it doesn't give me all the indexes:

```
t = [(index, row.index(1)) for index, row in enumerate(x) if 1 in row]
```

Basically, it gives me only one of the index in each row `[(0, 0), (1, 2)]`.

Comment: is this actually a numpy array?

Comment: yes, its <type 'numpy.ndarray'>. I actually have a large 2d array and I got that from extracting an image.

Comment: are there only ones and zeros?

Comment: not in my actual 2d array, but in the example yes.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to return a tuple of arrays of x and y indices where a given condition holds in an array.

If `a` is the name of your array:

```
>>> np.where(a == 1)
(array([0, 0, 1, 1]), array([0, 1, 2, 3]))
```

If you want a list of (x, y) pairs, you could `zip` the two arrays:

```
>>> list(zip(*np.where(a == 1)))
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)]
```

Or, even better, @jme points out that `np.asarray(x).T` can be a more efficient way to generate the pairs.

Comment: Just a note: `zip(*x)` can be slow for large `x`, where `x = np.where(a == 1)`. If a 2d array is fine, `np.asarray(x).T` is quite a bit faster, and if you *really* want a list-of-lists, `np.asarray(x).T.tolist()` is marginally faster.

Comment: Is it possible to do something similar but with the index where the 2d array is nearest to a given value, e.g. np.where_is_nearest_to(0.99)?

Answer (score 20):

Using numpy, [argwhere](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) may be the best solution:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([[1, 1, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 1, 1],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0]])

solutions = np.argwhere(array == 1)
print(solutions)

>>>
[[0 0]
 [0 1]
 [1 2]
 [1 3]]
```

Answer (score 15):

The problem with the list comprehension you provided is that it only goes one level deep, you need a nested list comprehension:

```
a = [[1,0,1],[0,0,1], [1,1,0]]

>>> [(ix,iy) for ix, row in enumerate(a) for iy, i in enumerate(row) if i == 0]
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)]
```

That being said, if you are working with a numpy array, it's better to use the built in functions as suggested by ajcr.