# find nonzero indices as an array

Tags: python, numpy

I know [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy.where) gives a tuple of the array coordinates where the condition applies. But what if I want an array?
assume the following 2d array:

```
a=np.array([[1 1 1 1 0],
            [1 1 1 0 0],
            [1 0 0 0 0],
            [1 0 1 1 1],
            [1 0 0 1 0]])
```

Now what I want is only the first occurrence of zeros, but for every row, even if it doesn't exist. Something like `indexOf()` in Java. So the output look like:

```
array([-1,2,2,1,0])
```

I need to cut pieces of an ndarray and it would be much easier to reduce a dimension rather than having a tuple and try to regenerate the missing rows.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27175400/how-to-find-the-index-of-a-value-in-2d-array-in-python I hope this helps

Comment: Is there a relation between the matrix presented and the sample output?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, but OP is confused between row and column.

Comment: Also, there should be commas in there for the example to be copyable Python syntax

Comment: That output doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: @AntonvBR. It's for the transpose. First *column* has no zeros, so -1. Next two columns have first zero in row 2, etc.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for poitning that out..

Comment: In the latest `numpy`, the `str()` omits the commas, `repr()` includes them, and makes for easier copy-n-paste.

Comment: @MadPhysicist is right, I meant columns and mentioned rows in my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243955/numpy-first-occurrence-of-value-greater-than-existing-value) what you are looking for?

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
            [1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]])

np.argmax(a==0, axis=0) - ~np.any(a==0, axis=0)
```

Output:

```
array([-1,  2,  2,  1,  0], dtype=int64)
```

The idea here is that `np.argmax` finds the index of the first matching element in each column (`axis=0` for *columns*, which appears to be what you want in the output, but if you actually want *rows*, use `axis=1`).  Because `np.argmax` returns 0 for columns that do not match at all, I subtract 1 from the result for each column that doesn't contain any 0.

Comment: `a.argmin(0)-a.all(0)` as a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a less crafty solution but arguably easier to undestand. 
First finds all matches and then creates an array with the first element of the matches and -1 if len == 0.

```
a=np.array([[1,1,1,1,0],
        [1,1,1,0,0],
        [1,0,0,0,0],
        [1,0,1,1,1],
        [1,0,0,1,0]])

matches = [np.where(np.array(i)==0)[0] for i in a.T]
np.array([i[0] if len(i) else -1 for i in matches]) # first occurence, else -1

array([-1,  2,  2,  1,  0])
```