# How to return the index of an element in a 2d array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

Assuming I want to use the position of an element in a 2d list knowing the element itself, what would be the command to find the index?
For a simple list the method `list.index(element)` works, for example:

```
    my_list = ["banana", "yam", "mango", "apple"]
    print(my_list.index("yam")
    >> 1
    print(my_list[my_list.index("yam")])
    >> yam
```

But the same method doesn't work for 2d arrays. For example:

```
    array = [["banana", "yam"],["mango", "apple"]]
    print(array.index("yam"))
```

I get a `ValueError: 'yam' is not in list.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the index of a value in 2d array in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27175400/how-to-find-the-index-of-a-value-in-2d-array-in-python)

Comment: That is not a "2D array". That is just a list with other list objects in it. In any case, what value to do *expect*?

Comment: I expect the output to be [0][1] for yam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked fine. I wrote a function to return the index for any given element in the array!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

u may use this answer

```
c="yam"
index=[(i, fruits.index(c)) for i, fruits in enumerate(array) if c in fruits]
```

Answer (score 1):

this is my code

```
array = [["banana", "yam"],["mango", "apple"]]
for i,j  in enumerate(array):
     if "yam" in j:
         index=(i,j.index("yam"))
         break
print(index)
```

Comment: Thanks. So there really is no simpler way. I intend to use the found index just like I would for a simple list (for example to replace the element in that index by another one). I guess this is okay , thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use `np.where` in the following way:

```
a = np.array([["banana", "yam"],["mango", "apple"]])
list(zip(*np.where(a == "yam")))
>> [(0, 1)]
```

Comment: Is there another way without using numpy?

Comment: I don't know. Only if you do a manual search... for in for